# 2013 Workflow not sending email but a second one does

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

Created the exact same WF in another site and it worked perfectly.  Go to the production site recreate it and it does not send an email?  It does however log the name in the history list so I know it's firing.

Added a second WF that sends an email when a date field changes and that sends an email.

Why is this thing not sending the email?

[image]

Comment: what do you need to check in this if condition?

Comment: Log the Current Item:Encoded Absolute URL to check its value. Try to add "pause for a duration" before the action to see if the email is sent.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone ever runs into a like problem it came down to the length of the folder name.  I changed the spaces to underscores and the WF is functioning correctly now.